# preg_replace to remove some unwanted divs

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In the following code, I need to remove `<div class="grid_8"></div>.`
They will always be at the start and finish of my string, for example:

```
<div class="grid_8"><img src="http://rps.sanscode.com/site/assets/media/images/rps_mini_logo.png" border="0" alt="Rapid Print Solutions" style="margin-bottom: 30px;" /> 
<h1></h1> 
</div>
```

What is a suitable regex for preg_replace to remove it? 8 can be any number between 1 and 16.

Thanks

Jason

---

@Amjad...

Here is my code

```
public function fix_grid(){
     $result = db::query("select * from sc_content_components where component_value_1 like '%grid_%'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     foreach($result as $item){
  $json = json_decode($item['component_value_1']);
  if(is_null($json)) continue;
  $x = reset($json);

  echo htmlspecialchars($x);
  echo "<p>=======================<b>Changes to: </b></p>";

  $patterns = array('/^<(div)((?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:\'[^\']*\')|[^>\s]+))?)*)\s*(\/?)>/'
                  , '/<\/(\div+)[^>]*>$/');
  $x = preg_replace($patterns, array('',''), trim($x));
  echo htmlspecialchars($x);
  echo "<hr>";


  $json[0]=$x;
//  $ne['component_value_1'] = json_encode($json);
//  db::where('component_id', $item['component_id']);
//  db::update('sc_content_component', $ne);
     }

 }
```

I'm using the regex below (@Amjad Masad) and it doesn't remove the last div.

As you can see I am using trim and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Does the contents need to go, or just the wrapping DIVs, also, what else is present in the strings?

Comment: Sorry the contents needs to stay and the wrapping divs need to go away

Comment: I recall handling nested patterns using perl.  You can't do it in PHP as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the open

```
$patterns = array('/^<(div)((?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:\'[^\']*\')|[^>\s]+))?)*)\s*(\/?)>/'
                  , '/<\/div[^>]*>$/');
preg_replace($patterns, array('','');, trim($htmlString));
```

Comment: It's not removing the last `</div>`... what do i need to do. See here: http://rps.sanscode.com/template/fix_grid

Comment: Are you sure your using trim? anyways try removing the $ from the end of the second pattern.

Comment: I changed it to this: `/<\/div>$/` and it works. Is there a problem with that you can forsee?

Comment: should be good, the [^>]* is to handle anything between </div and > for instance a space, if you had one of these it would break

Answer (score 1):

For the stated problem, this is the solution:

**Edit**: expanded regex =

```
/^\s*<div\s (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)*
            (?<=\s)class\s*=\s*(["\'])\s*grid_(?:1[0-6]|[1-9])\s*\1
            (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)*
     >
     (.*)
     <\/div\s*>
\s*$/xs
```

replacement = `"$2"`

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler.

*If the 1 to 16 is significant and part of a greater range...*

```
$match = preg_replace("/^<([^>]*)grid_(1[0-6]|[1-9])([^>\d]*)>(.+)<([^>]*)>$/s","$4",trim($str),-1,$hmany);
if($hmany){
    echo "$match <br>";
}else{ echo "No match found! <br>"; }
```

*If the 1 to 16 is the only possible range and therefore irrelevant...*

```
$match = preg_replace("/^<([^>]*)>(.+)<([^>]*)>$/s","$2",trim($str),-1,$hmany);
if($hmany){
    echo "$match <br>";
}else{ echo "No match found! <br>"; }
```

Regards.